# Send and receive file using Python: FastAPI and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, fastapi

I'm trying to upload a file to a FastAPI server using requests.

I've boiled the problem down to its simplest components.

The client using requests:

```py
import requests

files = {'file': ('foo.txt', open('./foo.txt', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/file', files=files)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

The server using fastapi:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/file')
def _file_upload(my_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(my_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, log_level="debug")
```

Packages installed:

- fastapi
- python-multipart
- uvicorn
- requests

Client Output:
<Response [422]>
{'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'my_file'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}

Server Output:
INFO:     127.0.0.1:37520 - "POST /file HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

FastAPI expecting the file in the ***`my_file`*** field and you are sending it to the `file` field.

it should be as

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/file"
files = {'my_file': open('README.md', 'rb')}
res = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Also, you don't need a *tuple* to manage the upload file (we're dealing with a simple upload, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'foo.txt' from your request.

It should look like

```
files = {'file': open('./foo.txt', 'rb')}
```

Comment: the ('foo.txt', ... is to add a file-name to the post-request: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

I tried it without, and get same result.

Answer (score 0):

based on the documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

the following code should work (worked for me):

```
image = {'file':("your_file_name.extension", open("your_file_name.extension", 'rb'))}

resp = requests.post(url="your url", files=image)
```